# Receiving a python TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not StringVar

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to create a set of tkinter buttons for a python script that reads a text file containing a list of filenames, then searchs for those names in a directory selected by the user and copies any found files to another location stipulated by the user.

But i am receiving this error now that i have inserted buttons

```
    with open(filePath, "r") as fh:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not StringVar
```

Here's the code below:

```
import os
import shutil
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

def browse_button():
    filePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    
def browse_button():
    global folder_path
    folderPath = filedialog.askdirectory()

def browse_button():
    global destination
    destination = filedialog.askdirectory()

root = Tk()

filePath = StringVar()
lbl1 = Label(master=root,textvariable=filePath)
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1)
button2 = Button(text="Browse Text File", command=browse_button)
button2.grid(row=0, column=3)


folderPath = StringVar()
lbl1 = Label(master=root,textvariable=folderPath)
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1)
button2 = Button(text="Browse Source Folder", command=browse_button)
button2.grid(row=0, column=6)


destination = StringVar()
lbl1 = Label(master=root,textvariable=destination)
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1)
button2 = Button(text="Browse Destination Folder", command=browse_button)
button2.grid(row=0, column=9)
 
filesToFind = []
with open(filePath, "r") as fh:
    for row in fh:
        filesToFind.append(row.strip())


for filename in os.listdir(folderPath):
    if filename in filesToFind:
        filename = os.path.join(folderPath, filename)
        shutil.copy(filename, destination)

mainloop()
```

BELOW IS THE UPDATED CODE:

```
import os
import shutil
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

def browse_button_1():
    global filePath
    filePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()

def browse_button_2():
    global folder_path
    folderPath = filedialog.askdirectory()

def browse_button_3():
    global destination
    destination = filedialog.askdirectory()

def browse_button_4():
    global run
    run = runScript()

root = Tk()

def runScript():

    filesToFind = []
    with open(filePath.get(), "r") as fh:
        for row in fh:
            filesToFind.append(row.strip())

    for filename in os.listdir(folderPath.get()):
        if filename in filesToFind:
            filename = os.path.join(folderPath.get(), filename)
            shutil.copy(filename, destination.get())

filePath = StringVar()
lbl1 = Label(master=root,textvariable=filePath)
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1)
button2 = Button(text="Browse Text File", command=browse_button_1)
button2.grid(row=0, column=3)


folderPath = StringVar()
lbl1 = Label(master=root,textvariable=folderPath)
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1)
button3 = Button(text="Browse Source Folder", command=browse_button_2)
button3.grid(row=0, column=6)


destination = StringVar()
lbl1 = Label(master=root,textvariable=destination)
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1)
button4 = Button(text="Browse Destination Folder", command=browse_button_3)
button4.grid(row=0, column=9)


run = StringVar()
lbl1 = Label(master=root,textvariable=run)
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1)
button5 = Button(text="Run Script", command=runScript)
button5.grid(row=0, column=12)

mainloop()
```

The is the updated codes error:

Slightly different issue, I am recieving this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/********/Documents/test.py", line 30, in runScript
    with open(filePath.get(), "r") as fh:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: As the error said, `filePath` is `StringVar`, so use `filePath.get()` instead.  However `filePath` should be empty at that time.  You should put the code block inside a function, and then call it by clicking a button.  Also, why there are three `browse_button()` functions defined?

Comment: Thank you for your response, it's much appreciated, where do I placethe filePath.get()? I'd like to have three buttons one for the text file, another for the source directory and the last for the destination directory, is this the wrong way to do it?

Comment: You should create another button to perform the file copy.  Put the block from `filesToFind = []` to line before `mainloop()` to a function (of course change all `filePath` to `filePath.get()`, `folderPath` to `folderPath.get()` and `destination` to `destination.get()`) and assign the function to `command` parameter of the new button.  Also, you need to rename the three `browser_button()` functions.

Comment: Hi acw1668, Sorry for the radio silence and thank you for help so far! I have updated the code above and I am now receiving a slightly different error which you can see above. I have applied your changes but have i missed something? I defined the filestofind / for loop as a function but it does not want to be called from the button. Have I not defined the function correctly?

Comment: The `StringVar` are overwritten inside those `browse_button_x()` functions.

Comment: Thank you. So as an example the variable ```filePath = StringVar()``` should stay the same but the button functions variable also called ```filePath``` needs to change. I'm a little stumped on what to change it too? Should i be referencing the ```StringVar``` in the ```browse_button_x()```?